# OAuth client webapp with UAA server - error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am running the OAuth Client from this https://github.com/cfid/uaa-samples/tree/master/basic-java-client
When I try to access the the app, it redirects me to the UAA login page. after I enter credentials, I get the following error:

error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."

Looking at the logs on my client webapp, I see the following:

-- AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider: Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=
[authorization_code], code=[S9uXYsvgn4], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8081/sampleapp/login]}
[2018-07-29 15:23:38.759] samples/app - ???? [http-nio-8081-exec-4] ....  WARN -
-- RestTemplate: POST request for "http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token" result
ed in 401 (null); invoking error handler

I am not sure what the issue is. Looks like in the call to oauth/token, it should also send the client_id and client_secret? But from the logs above, it looks like its not sending them. Is that the issue? If yes, why are these parameters not sent? Any ideas?

Comment: The external OAuth server can not see your client. I am guessing that that might be your problem: redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8081/sampleapp/login]}

Comment: It does come back to the client url (http://localhost:8081/cfapps-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/login?code=26ChX4ffZr&state=IbC58O) and thats where I see the above error